# Converting org.w3c.dom.Element to org.dom4j.Element

Tags: java, xpath, dom4j

I want to use `javax.xml.xpath` XPath APIs for my XML Reading and writing.

My whole Application uses dom4j elements and now `javax.xml.xpath` API is not accepting `org.dom4j.document`. So I have converted those documents to `org.w3c.dom.Document` using the below code

```
org.w3c.dom.Document w3cDom = new DOMWriter().write(doc);
```

I have used for API's like evaluate and I have got node of type `org.w3c.dom`

Since my other code is of completely dom4j related, Is there any way where I can convert org.w3c.dom.(Node or Element) to org.dom4j.(Node or Element) ??

PS:- I don't want to use dom4j.XPath as it internally calls jaxen.jar

Comment: I am afraid two interwoven DOMs wiil not be the way to go. ***Better write your own XPath.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dom4j [`DOMReader.read()`](https://dom4j.github.io/javadoc/2.1.0/org/dom4j/io/DOMReader.html#read-org.w3c.dom.Document-) method:

```
org.w3c.dom.Document w3cDom = new DOMWriter().write(doc);
org.dom4j.io.DOMReader reader = new DOMReader();
org.dom4j.Document document = reader.read(w3cDoc);
```

Or use the [`DOMReader.readElement()`](https://dom4j.github.io/javadoc/2.1.0/org/dom4j/io/DOMReader.html#readElement-org.w3c.dom.Node-org.dom4j.Branch-) method.

Answer (score 1):

Saxon provides an implementation of the JAXP XPath API that is capable of reading DOM4J trees directly, without conversion to DOM. So you can have your cake and eat it.